# repair and renaming of msi file

Tags: windows-installer, repair

I installed program by org.msi file. Then I renamed org.msi to new.msi. If I run new.msi file and then choose "Repair" then I get error that there is no org.msi file. I know if I copy new.msi to org.msi then all will work even when I run new.msi. But is there way to force new.msi to repair program when org.msi is absent and cannot be placed in original folder?

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd have to uninstall the MSI, rename it and then reinstall it.  You could also break future servicing of the MSI because changes in MSI name [require a Major Upgrade instead of a Minor Upgrade](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/12/08/278746.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need details about this tool called ORCA :

[ORCA tool info from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It will help modifying the MSI file.